# Error message occurs when using pip install command

Tags: pip, package

I am trying to download a package called "ZigZag" https://pypi.org/project/ZigZag/. Unfortunately I get this error message below: I am pretty new to python and somewhat not able to find the error. Hopefully someone can help

```
Collecting ZigZag
      Using cached ZigZag-0.2.2.tar.gz (126 kB)
      Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
      Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    Building wheels for collected packages: ZigZag
      Building wheel for ZigZag (setup.py): started
      Building wheel for ZigZag (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
      Running setup.py clean for ZigZag
    Failed to build ZigZag
    Installing collected packages: ZigZag
      Running setup.py install for ZigZag: started
      Running setup.py install for ZigZag: finished with status 'error'
    Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
    Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tests
      copying .\tests\test_core.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tests
      copying .\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\zigzag
      copying .\zigzag\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\zigzag
      running egg_info
      writing ZigZag.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to ZigZag.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to ZigZag.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'ZigZag.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' anywhere in distribution
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'ZigZag.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
...
╰─> ZigZag
```